# Which one is best for performance from 'order' and 'sort_by'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Which one is best for performance ?

1) order (Database side calculation)

2) sort_by (Ruby side calculation)

As per my thought `sort_by` should be fast then `order`. Because `order` is perform from database side so it is slower and `sort_by` perform on ruby side after getting result but i am confusing by seeing this  result ex.

=> Normal query (take more time then `order` and `sort_by` query) :-

```
> User.all
SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
#<Benchmark::Tms:0x000000089e4398 @cstime=0.0, @cutime=0.0, @label="", @real=6.515499990200624e-05, @stime=0.0, @total=0.0, @utime=0.0>
```

=> Query using `order` with benchmark (take less time then normal query and `sort_by` query) :-

```
> User.order(:name)  # `order` query is perform in sql so should take more time
User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"   ORDER BY "users"."name" ASC
#<Benchmark::Tms:0x00000007ec48c8 @cstime=0.0, @cutime=0.0, @label="", @real=0.00014305600052466616, @stime=0.0, @total=0.0, @utime=0.0>
```

=> Query using `sort_by` with benchmark (take more then `order` query and less time then normal query) :-

```
> User.all.sort_by(&:name) # Not perform `order` from database side so should be faster then `order`
SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
#<Benchmark::Tms:0x0000000897e5c0 @cstime=0.0, @cutime=0.0, @label="", @real=0.0019228710007155314, @stime=0.0, @total=0.0, @utime=0.0>
```

**Conclusion :-**

Normal query real time     :- 6.515499990200624e-05

`order` query real time    :- 0.00014305600052466616

`sort_by` query real time  :- 0.0019228710007155314

From this conclusion can we say that :-

It's take too much time for normal query then applying `order` query.

we have to use `order` method to decrease query perform time ?

I always prefer `sort_by` as per my thinking.

Which one is the best :(

Comment: Why do you expect the database to be _slower_ than Ruby?

Comment: It's like myths that perform calculation as less as possible from database side to improve performace. Perform most calculatin from language side like ruby , php for better performance.

Comment: Optimised database queries will almost always be faster than application calculations. Your choice of PHP vs Ruby is also likely to be irrelevant here (can we stop perpetuating the *ruby == slow* fable?) -- the key issue with processing in *any* application language is memory consumption.

Comment: How many entries does our `users` table have? Hint: Benchmarks usually do not make much sense for small numbers and without repetition. I would suggest <1m a small number for a database table.

Comment: 6.515e-05 is less than 0.000143, not more -- a rather fundamental error in your analysis.

Comment: yep, `6.515e-05` is `0.00006515`, which is less than `0.000143`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Database processing is few orders of significance faster, than Ruby. And database processing scales exclusively well, whereas Ruby's processing slowdown is proportional to the increase of the size of data you are processing.

Processing with Ruby drastically increases both time and (especially) memory consumption, and it can easily overload the memory and ***never actually finish*** the processing having the dataset is "big".

Some calculations with 1_000_000 rows with Ruby would take ***few tens*** of seconds, whereas PostgreSQL would finish it within ***few*** seconds.

Comment: Right, sorting in the database should be faster. The benchmarks posted above are probably an anomaly. You may want to perform the benchmarking multiple times, taking into account warmup time of Rails. Also, look into `benchmark-ips` if you want an easy way to do this in Ruby.

Comment: And you can improve the performance of the database query even more by adding appropriate indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Your first assumption should always be that data manipulation in a database is going to be very much faster than in Ruby.

For a *small* subset of problems, you might choose not to use the database.

For example, if you have a record with multiple child records, and you have to read multiple child rows based on various criteria (active = true, date < today, transmitted = false etc), then it may be faster to read all of the child records with one query and then filter the ones you want from that data set using Ruby. This is particularly true if you're using eager loading.

However, this shouldn't be your first assumption.